# Custom Workflow activities in SharePoint 2013 for 2010 Workflows

Tags: 2010, 2013, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity

We need to create custom workflow activity in Visual Studio 2012 for SharePoint 2013 using 2010 workflows.

Can someone PLEASE guide me on how to do this as I am finding blogs for either SharePoint 2010 or 2013 but not 2010 workflow activity for 2013.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the same directions as for SP 2010.  I've done this and installed onto SP 2013 just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input. will update if done. BTW I have already tried doing this but get reference errors.